# How to send http request through SSL connection?

Tags: python, sockets, ssl

I'm trying to establish a connection to a https server, sending an HTTP request and then constantly listen to the opened connection. I'm able to establish the connection, but when I try to send the http message the server sends me an HTTP error 426 indicating problems with the TLS.

This is my code so far:

```
import socket
import ssl

host = 'a host'
port = a port

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM, 0)

wrapped_socket = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
wrapped_socket.connect((host, port))
message = b"POST / HTTP/1.1\n" \
      b"some headers\n" \
      b"\n" \
      b"a body"
print(wrapped_socket.send(message)) #prints 426
while True:
     data = wrapped_socket.recv(1024)
     if not data:
        break
     print("Received: " + str(data))
```

The message itself is definitely not the problem as I can send it via Postman and get the expected result (HTTP 200). After googling for a while I think the problem is, that I didn't set some sort of certificate. I tried some stuff involving SSL context, but this lead to handshake errors. I simply found so many different answers, using many different methods, packages and stuff, that I'm too confused to see the solution myself. Also my knowledge about network protocols and stuff is rather poor.

Comment: @KlausD. Is there a way to listen for messages with requests? Since there will come more messages after the direct response to my request the common use of requests wouldn't help me.

Comment: 426 does not indicate a problem but a protocol upgrade as used in websockets. You should use a websocket client library then.

Comment: @Avery I tried the solution given in the link, but I ran into `certificate verifiy failed`  during handshake. My certificate was generated by OpenSSL.